# How to make changes appear in another sheet only

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I have been playing with VBA for a while now, and I'm stuck on one particular problem. I have a master data sheet for a number of people, and then specific profiles for each person. All the data is contained in the master, and is simply referenced to in the profile.
Users will mostly be looking at the PROFILE, though. And any changes made, will likely be made to the profile, not the master, therefore overriding the existing code in the profile.

Is there any way for the user to type in a change in one sheet (profile), but have that change show up in another sheet (master), and only that sheet, without affecting the original (profile)?

Thanks for any help offered.

P.s. Yes I have considered the option of a worksheet change sub that then copies the results to the other sheet, but I don't know how to make the profile then change back to the original code in that cell. Additionally this would mess with the ability to CTRL+Z in order to undo a single change.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a third sheet ('template') where you keep the default values and formulas that you want to use in 'profile'. Then, you can just put a save button in the 'profile' sheet. This way, the user can make changes to its profile, using Excel's built-in undo mechanism when needed, and save her changes at the end. Your macro will copy all changes to 'master' and revert everything in 'profile' to its template form.

Notice that once the user hits 'save', they won't be able to undo, which is a limitation when using macros, but since the save action will be meant to be run only at the end, it shouldn't be a big issue.

You could automate this even further using the `Worksheet_Change` event, and skipping the save button. But since you mention the undo requirement, this option is only feasible if you are willing to write your own undo code/macro, which would require you to keep track of all changes made to the profile, which is not something trivial to accomplish.